# troubleshooting Python GCP Cloud Function failures due to Memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to troubleshoot my Python Cloud Function (256M memory limit) that retrieves web content and does some text analyses. Most of the time, the CF works fine. But for some URLs - it fails with the infamous "Memory limit exceeded" errors... I read through all discussions about possible causes of memory retention (like global fields, files, logging) and nothing seems to apply in my case.

What is more - when I memory profile execution of this CF logic (main methods) locally, I do not see any memory usage difference between processing events that do cause OOM in the  deployed Cf vs events that do not cause OOM ... See details below for how I was memory profiling locally.

So my questions are:

1. is there a way to catch this type of errors in my CF code - and either log it, at least, or abort execution gracefully?
2. is it possible to add more detailed instrumentation to a deployed Python CF to see more fine-grained memory usage? (I checked the GCP CLoud Profiler (https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python#standard-environment) - but it only does performance profiling, not memory)

Below are details of how I was trying to memory profile my CF locally.

First, I used the classic "**memory_profiler**" and annotated the main methods called in CF with **@profile**. The results showed that memory usage of the main method processing a "bad" event , that is causing Memory issue in GCP, is very similar to the memory usage while processing "good" events. Here is what it looks like: (important parts)

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
31     57.8 MiB     57.8 MiB           1   @profile
32                                         def get_html(url, timeout=None):
33                                             """
34                                             Adopted from boilerpipe3 __init__.py.
                                   
52     57.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       try:
53     57.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           request = Request(url, headers=headers)

58                                                 connection = urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)

...
67     63.6 MiB      2.8 MiB           1               data = connection.read()
 ...
77     42.3 MiB    -21.3 MiB           1               encoding = charade.detect(data)['encoding']
82     42.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           html = str(data, encoding, errors='ignore')
...                                        
101     42.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return status, html, error
```

As you can see - the memory usage is less than 100M here...

After seeing the same picture for different HTML content retrieved - I started getting suspicions that maybe memory_profiler does not show memory usage of ALL libraries being used if it is used in a "peak"-like way - say the 'charade' Python lib allocated a lot of memory internally to perform this operation "encoding = charade.detect(data)" - but released at on the completion - and , thus, it was not detected by the profiler as being ever used...

To test this theory - I decided to memory profile the whole PyCharm app + CF execution , using JConsole, since it is a Java app :) - assuming that any memory used by the Python app will be allocated in the PyCharm's process memory space, not a separate process (am I wrong here?). I was running GC before each application invocation. My goal was to check if I would see a difference in memory usage between "bad" vs "good" events - not trying to get an absolute amount of memory used, as it is hard to separate IDE vs app usage in this profiling.

Needless to say - I saw exactly the same memory usage profile :(

Thus the questions above - how could I get more insight into the memory usage of a Python CF as deployed in GCP? Any ideas for additional local troubleshooting are also very welcome :)

Comment: no, I'm not writing to files

Comment: Did you share the whole code of your function? The leak is maybe somewhere else

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it's not full code above - but I thought my question was more generic - how to look into memory allocation details of any code .... I will try to create a smaller version of this CF that I could share full code of - thank you for helping out!

Comment: Can you also provide your cloud function setup?

Comment: unfortunately, I was not able to replicate the issue in a minimum functionality CF .... I have a CF with HTML scraping/parsing only - and the same URLs that cause OOM in my prod env - are being processed either totally OK in the min Cf or they fail without an OOM but just hanging forever.... I am investigating further. ... maybe differences in Python libs I'm thinking ....

Comment: and this is why the original questions of options to profile/troubleshoot in-place in the prod env is getting more and more important :)