# GCP Cloud Function - how to get instance ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to find which Cloud Function **instance** was used to execute each of the [trigger] events?

To give some background: it is related to the other question I asked about memory profiling cloud function instances while running on GCP: [troubleshooting Python GCP Cloud Function failures due to Memory limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948657/troubleshooting-python-gcp-cloud-function-failures-due-to-memory-limit-exceeded)

AFAIK, and based on answers from Google support, there is no way to memory profile cloud functions in GCP :( .... So, I wanted to check one idea that maybe the memory leak is happening due to exceptions happening in a few CF executions **in the same runtime instance** - which somehow retains memory in the CF instance between the runs and eventually blows up.

For that , I need to be able to "pin" the CF logs to actual CF instances running - and I could not find anything in the CF logs that would give me this info so far

Thank you!!

Comment: Most languages have memory profiling libraries available. You can easily test a function's behavior for good and bad scenarios on your desktop by writing some glue code to make the function a program. Then you can use traditional debuggers to investigate.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work for this use case. Memory issue only happens in the deployed CF , on GCP. Running the same function, processing the same data , locally - does not result in any significant memory use

Comment: do you use gen1 or gen2 cloud functions?

Comment: it is gen1 as of now

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> Most languages have memory profiling libraries available. You can easily test a function's behavior for good and bad scenarios on your desktop by writing some glue code to make the function a program. Then you can use traditional debuggers to investigate.

Yes, it is true that most languages have memory profiling libraries available. Memory profiling libraries allow you to measure the memory usage of your program and identify any memory leaks.

You can use this information to identify any memory leaks in your function. For example, if the memory usage of the function keeps increasing even after it has finished executing, then there is likely a memory leak.

---

There are a couple workarounds you can employ, though, as there is no direct method in Gen1 to obtain the instance ID of a GCP Cloud Function:

- Make use of the context object. Every Cloud Function invocation receives a context object, which holds details about the event that caused the invocation. The `executionId` is a field in the context object. With the help of this ID, you may link logs and other data to the precise instance that carried out the function.
- Utilize the logging API for Cloud Functions. You can obtain logs from Cloud Functions instances using the Cloud Functions logging API. You can view the logs for a particular instance by using this API to filter logs by execution ID.

Comment: Thank you, @chanpols ! Unfortunately, as I already mentioned, memory utilization does not show any signs of issues when run locally, only on GCP.  As per logging - yes, I definitely see the 'executionId' - but it is only useful to track logs for one specific execution of a CF, and it does not let you see which of the actual underlying CF instances is executing this request. I may have 5 instances of CFs active, with hundreds events processing through - and executionId is only unique to each event / individual execution of the CF, with no indication of. which of the 5 CF instances serves them

Comment: and this is why I was asking if there is a way to determine the actual CS instance ID - to see which executionIds were served/processed by the same CF instance